# scrapy can't load libxslt.1.dylib on my mac

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

I use `pip install scrapy` to install scrapy

But I run `scrapy` get below error:

```
➜  source  scrapy      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Reason: image not found
```

It's strange scrapy look for libxslt.1.dylib in my /opt/ floder...

And I run `pip install scrapy`, get this:

```
➜  ~  pip install scrapy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect>=0.9 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): queuelib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): w3lib>=1.8.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Twisted>=10.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): service-identity in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cryptography>=0.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.interface>=3.6.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): characteristic>=14.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1-modules in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipaddress in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna>=2.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.1.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1.0->cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
```

Help!!

Update in 2015/11/06

Hi, Joe Young.

I have try this `brew install libxml2 libxslt`.But it doesn't work, It seems like my python's look path is wrong?

```
➜  haimi git:(V3.2.0) brew install libxml2 libxslt
Warning: libxml2-2.9.2 already installed
Warning: libxslt-1.1.28_1 already installed
➜  haimi git:(V3.2.0) ✗ scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Reason: image not found
➜  haimi git:(V3.2.0) ✗
```

Comment: please update your question, `can't run on mac` is too broad

Comment: Ok, I will update it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need the libxslt and libxml libraries which are required by the lxml python package, which is required by scrapy.

If you install the "X-code Command Line Tool package", it should include these libraries for you.  There's a guide here: http://quantgreeks.com/how-to-install-xcode-command-line-tools-in-osx-yosemite/

Essentially it boils down to running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I have try this, and I install the "X-code Command Line Tool package" after `xcode-select --install`. 
And after install run `xcode-select --install`, get this:
`xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`, but the problem is not solved. My english is pool...

Comment: You can try to install it with homebrew if you have it `brew install libxml2 libxslt`  https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/What-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk